# I cant even print a nullable value

Tags: flutter, dart

basically the problem is clear :
here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.limeAccent[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
            topRight: Radius.circular(60),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.brown[900]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.brown[800]!,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                hintText: 'Type Your Task ...',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green[900],
                ),
                helperStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown[900],
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.brown[900]!,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                //     .addTask(newTaskTitle);
                // Navigator.pop(context);
                print(newTaskTitle);

                // Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                //     .addTask(newTaskTitle);
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[900]),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                    (states) => Colors.lightGreen),
                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => 6),
                shadowColor:
                    MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.green),
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                    (states) => Size.square(40.67)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me ...at this stage I just want to print the value that the user enters in the text field in the console ...but it gives me error :
LateInitializationError: Local 'newTaskTitle' has not been initialized.
i have also changed it to a stateful  widget to check if it works with setstate but it didnt ..
i also made it nullable like this => String? newTaskTitle; and Ofcourse it made to change a lot of things but at last the null value was passed ...there is a problem whithin the onChange callback of the textfield that doesnt assign the new value of user input to the variable i have created ...
How can I fixe this problem  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```dart
    late String newTaskTitle;
```

to

```dart
    ValueNotifier<String> newTaskTitle  = ValueNotifier("");
```

and put ElevatedButton inside ValueListenableBuilder
like this

```dart
   ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
     listenable : newTaskTitle,
     builder : (ctx,taskt,_){
      return ElevatedButton(
          onPressed : taskt.isEmpty ? null : (){
               // put you logic
            }
          .....
       );
    }

  );
```

change  onChanged of textField like this

```dart
onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle.value = newText;
              },
```